# How to click on a specific link within a TableCell with multiple links using Selenium WebDriver and Page Object Pattern?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, page-object-gem

I'm trying to use Selenium with WebDriver and the Page Object Pattern to open links in a table. I do not have any control over the web page code.

Also please note, this is a simplified example however it does work and shows the issue.

Working Code:
https://gist.github.com/charlesgreen/b80ed7e164b7199eaa44229e104f4428

The table has a column with 1 or 2 links in a single cell.

For cells with only 1 link, I am able to open the link by calling .link_element.click on the cell.

For cells with 2 links, this opens the first link in the cell but I am trying to open the second link (facts). Is there a way to click on only the Facts link in the cell (i.e. index or iteration)?

Note:
The original website I am working with both links open however I am unable to reproduce the issue locally With this said, it is not my objective. I am trying to open the second link. This is reproducible in the code below along with the gist link above.

```
# products.rb
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require './product_page'

Selenium::WebDriver.logger.output = 'selenium.log'
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = '/Applications/chromedriver'
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

# UPDATE File path
browser.get('file:///Users/name/products/index.html')

product_page = ProductPage.new(browser)
product_page.open_facts_link


# product_page.rb
require 'page-object'

class ProductPage
    include PageObject
    table(:products, id: 'products')

    def open_facts_link
       products_element[2][0].link_element.click
    end
end


# index.html - validated with https://validator.nu/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Link Page</title>
    <script>
        function OpenPhotos(val) {
            var opened = window.open("");
            opened.document.write("<html><head><title>Photos</title></head><body>Photos</body></html>");
        }

        function OpenFacts(val) {
            var opened = window.open("");
            opened.document.write("<html><head><title>Facts</title></head><body>Facts</body></html>");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="products">
        <tr>
            <th>Links</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a id="A_35" href="javascript:OpenFacts('35')" target="_blank">Facts</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>Product 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a id="A_36" href="javascript:OpenPhotos('36')" target="_blank">Photos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="L_36" href="javascript:OpenFacts('36')" target="_blank">Facts</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>Product 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: IMO, while creating the pseudo HTML for reference accidentally the uniqueness of `id` got lost in `<a id="A_36" href="" target='_blank'>Facts</a>`

Comment: That is a bit unusual that one `click` call would trigger 2 different links. Can you create a reproducible test case (ie HTML and page object code)? The current example seems to be too oversimplified as I am unable to reproduce the problem and it generates exceptions.

Comment: @DebanjanB thank you for the note. I fixed the ID.

Comment: @JustinKo thank you for taking a look at the code. I've added the page object code. I don't know why 1 click would trigger both elements. Perhaps it is an implementation detail with the way the `.link_element.click` methods works on the table cell.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce the issue using the updated code/HTML. Which driver are you using? Does the problem happen in multiple drivers?

Comment: I'm using the selenium webdriver with chrome. Which link would you expect to open?

Comment: I would expect an exception given the current code/HTML since there's no second `td` element in the row. Assuming the `td` does exist, I would expect the first link in the cell to be clicked.

Comment: @JustinKo thank you for your continued help. I've updated the description, code, and added a working example in the gist link above. Please see the description and notes section for full details. Thanks again it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click the different links in the same cell, you can pass a locator to `link_element` to be more specific. In this case, you could use the `href` attribute to differentiate the 2 links:

```
# Click Facts link
products_element[2][0].link_element(href: /OpenFacts/).click

# Click Photos link
products_element[2][0].link_element(href: /OpenPhotos/).click
```

Comment: Thank you @JustinKo for all your help.